# Turning a matrix to dummy matrix

Tags: pandas, python-2.7

I've generated a list of combination and would like to turn it into "dummies" matrix

```
 import pandas as pd
 from itertools import combinations
 comb = pd.DataFrame(list(combinations(range(1, 6), 4)))

    0 1 2 3
 0  1 2 3 4
 1  1 2 3 5
 2  1 2 4 5
 3  1 3 4 5
 4  2 3 4 5
```

would like to turn the above dataframe to a dataframe look like below.  Thanks.

```
    1 2 3 4 5
 0  1 1 1 1 0
 1  1 1 1 0 1
 2  1 1 0 1 1
 3  1 0 1 1 1
 4  0 1 1 1 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`MultiLabelBinarizer`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer.html):

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

lb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
df = pd.DataFrame(lb.fit_transform(comb.values), columns= lb.classes_)

print (df)

   1  2  3  4  5
0  1  1  1  1  0
1  1  1  1  0  1
2  1  1  0  1  1
3  1  0  1  1  1
4  0  1  1  1  1
```